# Issue using an array containing criteria with wildcards

Tags: arrays, powershell, wildcard

I've been trying to run a powershell code to split a file in 2.

I've got a couple of regular arrays, that works just fine. 
The 3rd array contains wildcards for each of the criteria, and that doesn't work at all.

I've tried -in -notin, -like -notlike, -contains -notcontains, -match -notmatch, i'm not getting the results I want.

```
    $NonAutoStructure = @("Not_Found", "UK Training Centre", "IRISH Training Centre", "Head Office", "UK Newmedica")
$AutoJournalDescriptions = @("STORE TRANFrom *",  "*SALES BANKED*")#, "*/* CREDIT" , "BANKING DIFF*BQ*" , "*/* MASTERCARD/VISA")  
$InactiveStores = @("4410", "0996", "1015", "5996")


$NonAutoJournalCompanies = {$_.Description -notcontains $AutoJournalDescriptions} 
$AutoJournalCompanies = {$_.Description -contains $AutoJournalDescriptions}
#$NonAutoJournalCompanies = {$_.structure -in $NonAutoStructure -or $_.Company -in $InactiveStores -and  $_.Amount -ne "0.00"}
#$AutoJournalCompanies = {$_.structure -notin $NonAutoStructure-and $_.Company -notin $InactiveStores -and  $_.Amount -ne "0.00"}

$UNREC_S0 | Where-Object $NonAutoJournalCompanies | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\*****$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\TestNonAutoJournal.txt -notype
$UNREC_S0 | Where-Object $AutoJournalCompanies | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\*****$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\TestAutoJournal.txt -notype
$UNREC_S0 | Where-Object $ZeroValuelines | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\*****$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\TestZeroLines.txt -notype
```

The Array I have issues with is the $AutoJournalDescriptions. I can only get it working if the array contains a single criteria. Otherwise, it seems to ignore them all. 
Here it only contains a couple, but the criterias after the # should be included too. 
I'm trying to include and exclude these criterias as part of #(Non)AutojournalCompanies files so that all data is preseverd, but separated and can then be directed towards different process streams.

Perhaps i'm simply trying to use a function that isn't meant to work that way...?
I've been searching for a solution all day to no avail. 
I could type all those criterias individually in the file production criteria, but that makes it heavy to read and cumbersome to maintain. I would prefer to enrich/modify the array when changes are required.

I hope that all makes sense. 
I'm pretty new to powershell.

Many thanks,

Antoine

Comment: For wildcards, you will need to use `-like` or `-notlike`. Since `-match` and `-notmatch` use regex, `*` is a special character. In regex, `-match 'sales banked'` would match the same results as  `-like "*sales banked*"`

Comment: Btw you don't need the `@( )` to make arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In order to match against *wildcard* patterns (such as `*SALES BANKED*`), you need the `-like` operator; by contrast, `-contains` performs *equality* comparisons (implicit `-eq` against each array element).
- While these operators (along with others, such as `-eq` and `-match`) support an array of *input* values<sup>[1]</sup>, the ***comparison operand* (typically, the RHS) must be a *scalar* (single value)** - you cannot compare the input array against *multiple* values at the same time.

---

In your scenario, your best bet is to use *regexes* ([regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)) rather than wildcard expressions, and to combine them into a *single* regex with the alternation operator (`|`), so you can use a single `-match` operation to test for multiple patterns:

```bash
# Sample input
$UNREC_S0  = [pscustomobject] @{ Description = 'A SALES BANKED baz' }, 
             [pscustomobject] @{ Description = 'bar' }, 
             [pscustomobject] @{ Description = 'STORE TRANFrom foo' }, 
             [pscustomobject] @{ Description = 'unrelated' }

# The filtering criteria: *regexes* to match against the descriptions,
# combined into a single regex with the alternation operator, '|'
$AutoJournalDescriptions = '^STORE TRANFrom ', 'SALES BANKED' -join '|'

# Construct script blocks to use with `Where-Object` below.
$NonAutoJournalCompanies = { $_.Description -notmatch $AutoJournalDescriptions } 
$AutoJournalCompanies =    { $_.Description -match $AutoJournalDescriptions}

$UNREC_S0 | Where-Object $NonAutoJournalCompanies | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\*****$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\TestNonAutoJournal.txt -notype
# ...
```

The above yields the following CSV data, showing that only the descriptions *not* matching the regexes were exported:

```bash
"Description"
"bar"
"unrelated"
```

Note how regex `^STORE TRANFrom`  corresponds to wildcard expression `STORE TRANFrom *`, and `SALES BANKED` to `*SALES BANKED*`.

The wildcard `*` operator - which normally correspond to `.*` in a regex - isn't needed in the regexes here, because the `-match` operator implicitly performs *substring* matching (whereas wildcard-matching with `-like` matches against the *whole* input string).

---

#### Optional reading: Filtering an array of string values by an array of substrings or patterns:

If you formulate your **criteria as *regexes* (regular expressions), you can use the `Select-String` cmdlet**, which *does* support multiple comparison operands:

```bash
# Sample input
$descriptions = 'A SALES BANKED baz', 'bar', 'STORE TRANFrom foo', 'unrelated'

# The filtering criteria: *regexes* to match against the descriptions.
$descriptionRegexes = '^STORE TRANFrom ', 'SALES BANKED'

($descriptions | Select-String -Pattern $descriptionRegexes).Line
```

Note: You can **also use this technique for finding *literal substrings***, by using **`-SimpleMatch`** instead of `-Pattern`, but note that substrings are then matched *anywhere* in each input string, without being able to restrict matching to, say, the start of the string.

The above outputs the following (a 2-element array):

```
A SALES BANKED baz
STORE TRANFrom foo
```

---

You can use a **similar approach by *combining* the individual regexes into a single one with the alternation (`|`) operator**, which **enables use of the `-match` operator**:

```bash
# Sample input
$descriptions = 'A SALES BANKED baz', 'bar', 'STORE TRANFrom foo', 'unrelated'

# The filtering criteria: *regexes* to match against the descriptions,
# combined into a single regex with the alternation operator, '|'
$descriptionRegex = '^STORE TRANFrom ', 'SALES BANKED' -join '|'
# -> '^STORE TRANFrom |SALES BANKED'

$descriptions -match $descriptionRegex
```

You can also **adapt this approach to *literal substring* matching**, namely by *escaping* the substrings for literal use inside a regex with **`[regex]::Escape()`**; e.g., 
`$descriptionRegex = ('yes?', '2.0').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'`

---

Otherwise, **if you do need *wildcard* support, you'll have to - inefficiently - *nest loops*** (see shortcut below, if you can make specific assumptions):

```bash
# Sample input
$descriptions = 'A SALES BANKED baz', 'bar', 'STORE TRANFrom foo', 'unrelated' 

# The filtering criteria: wildcard patterns to match against the descriptions.
$descriptionWildcards = 'STORE TRANFrom *', '*SALES BANKED*'

foreach ($descr in $descriptions) {
  foreach ($wildcard in $descriptionWildcards) {
    if ($descr -like $wildcard) { $descr; break }
  }
}
```

Note that I've used `foreach` *statements* rather than the pipeline with a `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* call; the former is faster, the latter can keep memory consumption constant if the input is being *streamed*; with arrays already in memory, in full, the `foreach` statement is the better choice.

---

You can take a **shortcut**, IF you can make **two assumptions**:

- No single wildcard pattern matches *more than one* input.
- The input order needn't be preserved; that is, it is acceptable that the output order of descriptions reflects the order of the entries in the wildcard-pattern array, not the order of the input descriptions.

```bash
# Sample input
$descriptions = 'A SALES BANKED baz', 'bar', 'STORE TRANFrom foo', 'unrelated' 

# The filtering criteria: wildcard patterns to match against the descriptions.
$descriptionWildcards = 'STORE TRANFrom *', '*SALES BANKED*'

# Loop over the criteria and match the descriptions against each.
# `foreach` is the built-in alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.
# The output order will be reflect the order of the wildcard patterns.
$descriptionWildcards | foreach { $descriptions -like $_ }
```

In this case, while the resulting elements are the same, their ordering differs:

```
STORE TRANFrom foo
A SALES BANKED baz
```

---

<sup>[1] With an array of values as input, these operators act like *filters*: that is, they return the *sub-array* of matching values; e.g., `1, 2, 3 -eq 2` returns `2` as a single-element array.</sup>