# Powershell remove any lines from big text file containing any of a large number of strings

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, data-processing

We have a large (~100MB) text file.
We need to remove any lines that contain certain phrases. I would like to use PowerShell to replace the current method of doing it, which uses windows grep and is a .bat file.

The problem is, there are about 95 key phrases. any line containing any of these phrases must be removed.

The list of key phrases is contained in `"badPhrases.txt"`, line delimited like a regular text file. There are like 100 of them, I don't want to include them in a hard-coded list, but I will if I have to.

I have tried a couple/few comparisons, but my output is always LARGER than my original input file! Or, 0k(empty). What am I doing wrong? I suspect the problem is in the `Where-Object` filter, but I could be wrong.

```
[string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path '.\badPhrases.txt'
get-content ".\inputfile.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -notlike $arrayFromFile} | Out-File ".\clean_data.txt" -Force
```

I've tried -notlike, -notin -notmatch and -notcontains (while flipping the array & the input object around in ways that seemed logical). Such as...

```
Where-Object {$arrayFromFile -notin $_}
....
Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $arrayFromFile}
....
Where-Object {$_ -notlike arrayFromFile}
```

I have searched stackOverflow and googled around and I'm not able to find any links that aren't dead, that address this exact use case. There was a "hey scripting guy" reference, but... the link was dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Select-String`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/), which supports multiple search criteria via an array of strings passed to its 
`-Pattern` parameter:

```
Select-String -NotMatch -SimpleMatch -Pattern (Get-Content -Path .\badPhrases.txt) .\inputfile.txt |
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | 
   Out-File .\clean_data.txt -Force
```

**Character-encoding caveat:** In Windows PowerShell, `Out-File` creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files by default, where each character is represented by (at least) *2* bytes; in PowerShell [Core] 6+, the default is more sensibly BOM-less UTF-8; use the `-Encoding` parameter to control the character encoding explicitly.

- `-NotMatch` negates the matching, so that only lines *not* matching any of the pattern strings are output.
- `-SimpleMatch` ensures that the patterns are matched *literally* against the lines of the input file; by default, they're interpreted as regular expressions.
- Note that matching is case-*insensitive* by default; use `-CaseSensitive`, if needed.
- Since `Select-String` outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo)instances by default, `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line` is needed to extract the lines themselves.

  - Note: In PowerShell 7+, you can use `Select-String`'s `-Raw` switch instead.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$_ -notlike $arrayFromFile`

You cannot use an array as the *RHS* of string-comparison operators such as `-like`, `-match`, `-eq` - you can only match against *one* string at a time.

(Apart from that, `-like` / `-notlike` match against the *entire* LHS by default; to match a *substring* of the LHS, you'd have to put `*` on either end of the RHS.)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650023/45375) for more information.

> `$arrayFromFile -notin $_`
>
> `$_ -notcontains $arrayFromFile`

In principle, you'd have to *reverse* the operands for [containment operators `-in` and `-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-7#containment-operators) and their negations - the syntax is `<array> -contains <value>` and `<value> -in <array>` - but the problem is that that, again, matching of the *entire* strings is performed either way, so this approach would only work if `$arrayFromFile` contained *full lines* present in the input (`-in` and `-contains` implicitly perform per-element `-eq` comparisons).

Comment: When I ran it that way, my output file ended up still larger than my input file! However: I have noticed, and I neglected to mention this detail, that some of the 'bad phrases' contain special characters; such as Greater Than, Less Than, Commas, slashes, and back slashes. Do you think I need to escape out these special characters, or maybe encapsulate them in quotes in the 'badPhrases.txt' file?

Comment: @Pink: The size increase most likely comes from `Out-File` in Windows PowerShell (but not PowerShell Core) creating "Unicode" files (UTF-16LE) - please see my update. No, if you use `-SimpleMatch`, you needn't escape the special characters.

Comment: This is awesome, THANK YOU so very much.. So it appears to be working; I am trying to compare-object with the output from the older .bat file that used grep and took 100 years. the diff is taking some time. i changed output file type to utf8, not due to compatibility considerations, but just so that I could see really quick if my output was anything close to the other method. (It is; this method is ~ 69MB and the other is ~71Mb). will mark as answered soon!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Pink. Was the result as expected? Note that saving as UTF-8 in Windows PowerShell invariably prepends the 3-byte UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: Yes - This appears to have worked perfectly. In fact it caught a few thousand lines that the 'grep' based batch file we had wasn't getting! I would never have come up with the select-string and the expand thingy so Thanks a ton! We're not as worried about file format as I thought; these files won't be going back to the mainframe where they originated.