# Comparing two arrays with wildcards

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare the add/remove programs on a computer and want to compare it to a list of software on a file share so that helpdesk knows which licensed software they need to install. I created the following script and for some reason I get the error I am missing a bracket. I think the syntax is fine or maybe I missed something?

I really appreciate your help

```
$approvedSoftware = @(Get-ChildItem -Path '\\fileshare\Applications'| Select-Object Name)

$computer= @(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName)


foreach ($program in $computer)
{
if ("*$program*" -like $approvedSoftware)
{
Write-Host "$($program)"
}
}
```

Comment: `if (approvedSoftware -like "*$program*")` you're missing a `$` in your var :)

Comment: Check your syntax. It's in your 2nd line, you start `@(` but never close it.

Comment: Thank you both, I have edited the script and added your suggestions. I get no output in powershell? Please see above for the modified script.

Comment: I assume $approvedSoftware is a list? Then it should be `if ($program -in $approvedSoftware)`

Comment: Hello andr3yk it's a list of folders

Comment: @ryan4u2 you would need to make both a list of strings, e.g. `$approvedSoftware = Get-ChildItem -Path '\\share\Applications' | select -ExpandProperty Name`, if you want to keep it to directories only add `-Directory` to `Get-Content`. Then you can experiment with `Compate-Object` and use 2 lists to compare. Would be easier to help if you can provide a sample of few non-sensitive items from `$Computer` and `$approvedSoftware` variables

Comment: Hello @andr3yk I made a slight change to the script above to make it easier to look at. An example off $computer: LogMeIn Rescue Technician Console ,Microsoft Visual C++ 2013, Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649 ,Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X86 Additional Runtime - 14.28.29910 , MSXML 4.0 SP2 Parser and SDK.                                                                                                  And below is an example of $approved software: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1, Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2019, Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 ,  Microsoft Office Project Professional 2010

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly updated your suggested input data from the comment so there is 1 same in both arrays

Sample input data:

```
$computer = "LogMeIn Rescue Technician Console;Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649;Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X86 Additional Runtime - 14.28.29910;MSXML 4.0 SP2 Parser;SDK".split(";")
$approvedSoftware = "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1;Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2019;Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016;Microsoft Office Project Professional 2010;Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649".split(";")
```

The input data needs to be 2 string arrays or have object with same property name to be compared.

Once you run `Compare-Object` on these arrays you can chose any of the criteria to filter the result based on `SideIndicator` property:

```
$Result = Compare-Object $computer $approvedSoftware -IncludeEqual
$Result

InputObject                                                    SideIndicator
-----------                                                    -------------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649   ==
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1                                 =>
Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2019                                 =>
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016                        =>
Microsoft Office Project Professional 2010                     =>
LogMeIn Rescue Technician Console                              <=
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X86 Additional Runtime - 14.28.29910 <=
MSXML 4.0 SP2 Parser                                           <=
SDK                                                            <=

$Result | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}

InputObject                                                    SideIndicator
-----------                                                    -------------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649   ==
```

Based on your code to list software that is installed and from approved list you need to do following:

```
$approvedSoftware = (Get-ChildItem -Path '\\fileshare\Applications').Name    
$computer = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName
$installedApprovedSoftware = (Compare-Object $computer $approvedSoftware -IncludeEqual `
  | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}).InputObject
$installedApprovedSoftware | Foreach {Write-Host $_}

Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40649
```

I am not certain on your requirement for wildcards based on the input data, but have provided a reference on how `-like` and wildcards can be used.

References:

`Compare-Object` documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1

Detailed answer on wildcard comparison:

[Issue using an array containing criteria with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648052/issue-using-an-array-containing-criteria-with-wildcards)

Comment: Thank you @andr3yk I am going to do some experimentation. The wildcards are for the folder names that contain the name of of application which is different in the add/remove programs of the pc. If you know a certain way to use wildcards when using compare-object cmdlet, it will be very appreciated!

Comment: @ryan4u2 sounds good. For wildcards you will need to go back to the for loop, as per your original approach, but you will need to do nested for loop as you will need to compare each object to each object in both arrays. e.g. `foreach ($program in $computer)
{
foreach ($software in $approvedSoftware) { if ($software -like "*$program*" ) { Write-Host $program } } }`